# Implementing a weighted graph class where inputs are <u,v,w> Python

Tags: python, oop, graph

I have been able to implement a graph class where each individual vertex are given first and the edges are added later. But this is a waste of memory.
Example of input:

```
total_vertices = 7
my_graph = Graph(total_vertices)
edges = []
edges.append((3,1,5))
edges.append((1,2,1))
my_graph.add_edges(edges)
```

Here is my code

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.vertices = [None] * N
        for i in range(N):
            self.vertices[i] = Vertex(i)

    def add_edges(self, edges_list):
        for edge in edges_list:
            u = edge[0]
            v = edge[1]
            w = edge[2]
            current_edge = Edge(u,v,w)
            current_vertex = self.vertices[u]
            current_vertex.add_edge_to_vertex(current_edge)

class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, vertex):
        self.vertex = vertex
        self.vertex_edges = []

    def add_edge_to_vertex(self, edge):
        self.vertex_edges.append(edge)

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, u, v, w):
        self.u = u
        self.v = v
        self.w = w
```

So I want to be implementing a graph class in python in which the input is in the form `<u,v,w>` where `u` is the parent vertex, `v` is the child vertex, and `w` is the weight straight away **without having to indicate the number of vertices first**. Input looks like this:

```
edgelist = [(0,2,4),(0,1,2),(0,3,3),(2,3,2), (3,0,3)]
graph = Graph(edgelist)
print(graph)
```

[image]

Any help/suggestions are most welcome

Sample input:

```
edgelist = [(0,2,4),(0,1,2),(0,3,3),(2,3,2), (3,0,3)]
graph = Graph(edgelist)
print(graph)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two properties: `self._nodes` and `self._edges` which will be modified each time you add a node or an edge. I just remove `Vertex` class but you can actually keep it (no need in your code), also the `Edge` class that I eventually didn't remove.

I modified edge tuple to differentiate nodes from weight...

```py
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges_list=None):
        self._nodes = []
        self._edges = []
        if edges_list is not None:
            self.add_edges(edges_list)

    def add_node(self, v):
        self._nodes.append(v)

    def add_edge(self, ab, w):
        a, b = ab
        if a not in self._nodes:
            self._nodes.append(a)
        if b not in self._nodes:
            self._nodes.append(b)
        my_new_edge = Edge(ab, w)
        self._edges.append(my_new_edge)

    def add_edges(self, e_list):
        for ab, w in e_list:
            self.add_edge(ab, w)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._nodes}\n{self._edges}"


class Edge:
    def __init__(self, ab, w):
        a, b = ab
        self._from = a
        self._to = b
        self._weight = w

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"from {self._from} to {self._to} weighted {self._weight}"


edgelist = [((0, 2), 4),
            ((0, 1), 2),
            ((0, 3), 3),
            ((2, 3), 2),
            ((3, 0), 3)]
g = Graph(edgelist)

print(g)
# [0, 2, 1, 3]
# [from 0 to 2 weighted 4, from 0 to 1 weighted 2, from 0 to 3 weighted 3, from 2 to 3 weighted 2, from 3 to 0 weighted 3]
```

**Edit** Add an optional argument to `Graph` constructor so that it accepts an edges list.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thank you for your help! But would there be a way to implement this without having to initialize the g = Graph( ) first and just get g = Graph(roads) straight away? like the example input I editted to the bottom of my question. Thanks!

Comment: It's easy to add an argument to the constructor. I just edited to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much, Do you think it'd be possible to put in the edges in O(V + E) complexity where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges? I see that in the add_edges class uses O(E) which calls add_edge that uses O(V) hence the final complexity would be O(VE)

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure, that if you want to have a O(V+E) complexity, you will have to declare your vertices and edges in two times (first nodes and finally edges), for you don't have to test if your nodes are already known (in the `self._nodes` list).

Comment: Apologies for so many questions. Could you please indicate how I can do so? My main goal is to implement the dijkstra algorithm, which I've done according to the codes above (which is wrong as the inputs are different) Thank you

Comment: As you want to keep `graph = Graph(edgelist)`, if you parse this list to find nodes: O(E) and not O(V)... so IMHO, you'd better `graph = Graph()` then for each node: `g.add_node(node)` and then for each edge weighted w : `g.add_edge(edge, w)` modifying the latter method removing tests (`if a in ... if b in `)

Comment: which is essentially why I had a vertex class as well. (Dijkstra requires self.discovered for each vertex etc). Really struggling with this and would be great if you could help with the vertex class as well. Thank you

Comment: You can easily add your `Vertex` class, each node is a `Vertex` instance and edges ard `Vertex` tuples.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could use dictionaries for storing vertices and edges:

```
import collections

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edge_list):
        self.edges = collections.defaultdict(dict)
        for u, v, w in edge_list:
            self.edges[u][v] = w

    def get_weight(self, u, v):
        return self.edges[u][v]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__qualname__}({dict(self.edges)})'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(dict(self.edges))
```

Usage:

```
# Create an instance of a graph
edgelist = [(0, 2, 4), (0, 1, 2), (0, 3, 3), (2, 3, 2), (3, 0, 3)]
graph = Graph(edgelist)
print(graph)

# Get the weight between u and v
u, v = 0, 1
print(graph.get_weight(u, v))
```

Comment: This works, but unfortunately I'm trying to do so without importing libraries... my bad, should've mentioned it. Thanks anyway

Comment: `defauldict` si from standard library. But if you don't want to use it, you can have `dict` instead.